# Is it possible to modify the time OSCeleton sends a lost_user event/message?

Tags: java, processing, osc

I'm playing around with [OSCeleton](https://github.com/Sensebloom/OSCeleton) and [Processing](http://processing.org) and succesfully got to track skeletons and do stuff.

**What I'm wondering is if there's any way to change the delay time a "lost_user" message is sent to Processing.** 
This is taking so long for what I'm trying to achive, since i need to stop tracking a user as soon as he goes away from the screen, so I can accept another user's interaction. (imagine an installation where a lot of people wants to play with).

any help/tips would be really appreciated.

Jon

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from the OSCeleton's source and with my minimal experience with the kinect(I never used OSCeleton), there is no way to modify that code to do that. It seems to be a thing handled even lower, by the driver or by the kinect its self(?).

Yet you need not bind yourself with that, and I would suggest a couple of ways to bypass the problem if I understand properly.

First, the latest drivers and examples should have multi-user support, meaning you can just arrange who is your main user. From what I can tell from the source you do get an osc message in Processing when a new user is detected as well as an ID number. You can put each new user that arrives, into an arrayList and figure out a way to do things without depending on the latest user.

If you are still going for the user-after-user thing though, or I was mistaken about the multi-user support(which is mentioned nowhere in the README), you can check yourself whether a user has left the area. Although you can not get a definitive answer like that you can check for example, whether a specific joint or all joints of a user have moved in the last 10-20 osc messages received. That probably means storing the position of this joint in an 10-20 item array and continuously updating while also doing a check on whether the items are different. If all items in the array are the same, your user has not moved a bit and thus probably should not be taken to account.

Last but not least you can switch to other solutions. The one I used about a year ago was "[Synapse for Kinect](http://synapsekinect.tumblr.com)" which also seems stale now. The latest you can use is a Processing library called [SimpleOpenNI](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/) which definitively have multi-user tracking and you won't need any intermediary programs running to give you the joints.

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Petros, thanks for replying. I took a quick look at the source, but since I'm kinda newbie on C, couldn't find the way, maybe this behaviour is handled by the OPENNI drivers.
Regarding your suggestions: yes, I actually did some of that. I did a skeleton object which receives the OSC data. I put them in an arrayList, and as far as I can tell, it works pretty well. The skels also remain "alive" (get drawn) when OSC messages are received within a certain time.

Comment: I've also tested with 4 users at a time. THE THING IS: OSCeleton supports 4 skels at a time (I've read that maybe 6), so if there're 4 skels in the screen, and one of them (or more) leaves the screen, sometimes it takes too long to send the "lost_user" message. When this happens, if there's another new user trying to interact, it may not recognize him until that message triggers. I'm thinking in an installation where is possible to have multiple users waiting to interact with. I think I'll figure it out somehow... already posted on the osceleton google groups, but nothing yet. Cheers!